# El texto con el nuevo privilegio ganado tiene un color que hace que apenas se distinga

Tags: bug, interfaz-de-usuario

El texto marcado con rojo en la imagen se monta sobre el elemento en azul

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se debería poder leer mejor es el privilegio que acabo de ganar, que dice:

> Establecer recompensas