# ¿Quién es el CM de SOes? ¿Qué procesos internos está habiendo?

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, meta-stackexchange, gerente-de-comunidad

En Meta.SE Juan M escribió a mediados de julio dos publicaciones:

- [New Resources for Our Stack Exchange Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312699/209901)
- [New Resources for Our Stack Exchange Network - Part 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313084/209901)

En la primera explica que pasa a dirigir un equipo que abarcará a toda la red de Stack Exchange, en lugar de su actual posición de responsable de los sitios internacionales (SOes, SOpt y SOja).

En la segunda indica que el actual CM de SOru pasa a serlo de todos los sitios internacionales. Se trata de [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/nicolas-chabanovsky).

No me queda claro si Juan M seguirá pendiente de SOes, pero parece que no.

Han pasado las semanas y no veo ninguna comunicación "oficial", pero sí he observado a Juan más activo en Meta SOes marcando alguna pregunta antigua como resuelta, etc, entiendo que preparando el traspaso de poderes.

Me surgen algunas dudas:

- ¿Cómo se gestionará a partir de ahora SOes? ¿Será Nicolas efectivamente  el CM de referencia con el que contactar en caso de problemas?
- ¿Qué ocurre con los bugs que se han acumulado con el tiempo y a los que no se ha encontrado recursos? Hace unos meses en el chat recopilamos los más urgentes y dio la sensación de que iban a resolverse, pero no ha sido el caso: tras comentarnos lois6b que Juan pedía una lista de bugs prioritarios, con Mariano (¡volvé!) nos pareció que podían ser estos:

  > LISTADO POR PRIORIDAD (Mariano)
  >
  > - [Las etiquetas con tildes se reproducen incorrectamente en la versión móvil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2221/83)
  > - [SOes y la publicidad de afiliados](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3148/83)
  > - [¿Podríamos tener un pequeño detector de publicaciones en inglés que notificara a los autores?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2043/83)
  > - [El texto con el nuevo privilegio ganado tiene un color que hace que apenas se distinga](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/727/83)
  > - [No se están resaltando las etiquetas con diacríticos agregadas en ediciones sugeridas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2234/83)
  >
  > <sub>chat Coincidencias solapadas, [16 de marzo de 2018](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43440768#43440768)</sub>
- Traspasar la barrera entre SOes y Stack Exchange ha sido siempre complicado, y el CM parece que estaba en el medio para ayudar en el proceso por el tema de la barrera lingüística. Sin embargo, muchos de nosotros participamos en distintos sitios también en inglés y parece que las cosas se mueven más y más rápido en Meta.SE, por ejemplo. ¿No sería interesante mover el foco hacia allá para que el CM no ejerza de tapón y estar en el mismo nivel que el resto de sitios de la red? ¿Qué ideas plantea SE como empresa para mejorar la situación actual?
- ¿Hay recursos para los SO internacionales? En los últimos años se ha pasado de un CM para cada uno de ellos a uno solo para los cuatro. Teniendo en cuenta que esto implica a una única persona gestionando cuatro idiomas tan diferentes como el ruso, el japonés, el portugués y el castellano, parece que la tarea puede resultar complicada.
- ¿Cómo se está gestionando la carga de trabajo de los moderadores? SOes es la 6.ª comunidad en número de preguntas diarias ([estadística completa](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#questionsperday)). La 7.ª es SOpt, que tiene el doble de moderadores. Aparte de Unix&Linux, el resto de sitios de entre los diez primeros tienen como mínimo 5 moderadores. ¿Está en la agenda del CM gestionar este tema? Las estadísticas de trabajo de los moderadores son obviamente privadas, pero me encuentro con que en general los reportes tardan bastante en resolverse ([y las consultas a veces no se contestan](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3593/83)).

En fin, todo este tochazo es para solicitar que se incida un poco en la seña de identidad de Stack Exchange: la transparencia. Dado que hay muchas horas metiéndole muchas horas a esto, creo bueno y necesario que se nos explique un poco los procesos internos que está habiendo cuando tienen afectación en SOes.

Comment: Es verdad, Nicolas será nuestro CM. Con respecto a que "los reportes tardan en resolverse", si notas esto es porque se da determinado tiempo a que nuevos usuarios puedan leer el  [tour]  para conocer el sitio y además puedan modificar su pregunta/respuesta de acuerdo al [help]. Los reportes en meta son menos comunes por eso (no menos prioritarios). **Personalmente me doy cuenta que el equipo actual de moderadores absorbe sin problema el trabajo de moderación con ayuda de varios miembros de la comunidad.** Saludos.

Comment: @fedorqui Aunque no soy el único CM de esta comunidad, seguiré activo aquí. No dejaré a esta comunidad por completo. Las demás preguntas que haces son buenas, estoy entre algunas cosas ahora, en cuanto las termine regreso a contestar. :)

Comment: Relacionado: [Comentarios e iniciativas en sitios internacionales](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3658/65)

Answer (score 4):

Para responder a tus preguntas:

> Cómo se gestionará a partir de ahora SOes? ¿Será Nicolas efectivamente
>   el el CM de referencia con el que contactar en caso de problemas?

El anuncio que se hizo sobre Nicolas incluye a este sitio como parte de su responsabilidad.  Pero, a pesar de la nueva estructura, seguiré estando presente en el sitio.  Nicolas es el contacto directo para esta comunidad al igual que para el equipo de moderadores.  Yo seguiré ayudándolo a guiar al sitio pero mi enfoque estará un poco más elevado ahora.  Estamos ahora tramitando los cambios y los anuncios vendrán para principios de septiembre siendo que Nicolas se va de vacaciones en unos días.

> ¿Qué ocurre con los bugs que se han acumulado con el tiempo y a los que no se ha encontrado recursos? Hace unos meses en el chat recopilamos los más urgentes y dio la sensación de que iban a resolverse, pero no ha sido el caso. Por si acaso, con Mariano nos pareció que podían ser: ....

Esto es un asunto súper importante que me agrada poder clarificar. Los bugs no son responsabilidad de los moderadores o de los Community Managers.  Lo que hacemos nosotros es avisar y trabajar con nuestro equipo interno (cuyo director es [Joe Friend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/354333/joe-friend)) para resolver nuestros problemas.  En cuanto nosotros les avisamos, ese equipo se encarga de investigar y fijar las fechas para solucionar y resolver nuestros reportes.  En otras palabras, los recursos los controla la empresa, no nosotros.  Lamentablemente, las respuestas han sido "ahora no se puede" o "lo estamos platicando pero no sabemos ahora cuándo podemos visitar ese asunto", lo cual es frustrante.  En caso de emergencia, se puedo hacer algo para resolver la situación pero el estado del equipo, con el número de desarrolladores que tenemos y los enfoques de la empresa, ha causado que las respuestas no sean favorables.

Tienen ellos ya la lista de los bugs y espero respuestas de ellos. En cuanto me las den se las puedo compartir. No es lo ideal, lo sé, pero es nuestra realidad.

> Traspasar la barrera entre SOes y Stack Exchange ha sido siempre complicado, y el CM parece que estaba en el medio para ayudar en el proceso por el tema de la barrera lingüística. Sin embargo, muchos de nosotros participamos en distintos sitios también en inglés y parece que las cosas se mueven más y más rápido en Meta.SE, por ejemplo. ¿No sería interesante mover el foco hacia allá para que el CM no ejerza de tapón y estar en el mismo nivel que el resto de sitios de la red? ¿Qué ideas plantea SE como empresa para mejorar la situación actual?

Vendrá un anuncio sobre esto. :)

> ¿Hay recursos para los SO internacionales? En los últimos años se ha pasado de un CM para cada uno de ellos a uno solo para los cuatro. Teniendo en cuenta que esto implica a una única persona gestionando cuatro idiomas tan diferentes como el ruso, el japonés, el portugués y el castellano, parece que la tarea puede resultar complicada.

Sí, lo es y lo seguirá siendo.  Queremos renovar la manera en que los sitios internacionales interactúan entre sí. Vamos a hacer unos cambios para implementar unas cosas que nos ayuden a hacer esto.  Vendrá un anuncio sobre esto también. :)

> ¿Cómo se está gestionando la carga de trabajo de los moderadores? SOes es la 6.ª comunidad en número de preguntas diarias (estadística completa). La 7.ª es SOpt, que tiene el doble de moderadores. Aparte de Unix&Linux, el resto de sitios de entre los diez primeros tienen como mínimo 5 moderadores. ¿Está en la agenda del CM gestionar este tema? Las estadísticas de trabajo de los moderadores son obviamente privadas, pero me encuentro con que en general los reportes tardan bastante en resolverse (y las consultas a veces no se contestan).

Nuestros moderadores han hecho un excelente trabajo.  Si se decide entre la comunidad, los moderadores, y los CM que se require tener más moderadores, tendremos otra elección.  Por ahora, seguiremos tal y como estamos pero eso puede cambiar también.

Nota: Por favor disculpen la brevedad, no quise que pasara mucho tiempo sin responder. ¡Seguimos adelante!

Comment: ¿Los anuncios se harán en [meta.se] o en nuestro meta?

Comment: En Meta Stack Exchange. :)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta :) Sería bueno que se haga un "mini anuncio" en nuestro meta también, hasta hoy me enteré que tenemos nuevo CM

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta, sí! Mi pregunta abarca muchos temas y me contestas a todos (¡fantástico!). Lo de los bugs me preocupa especialmente, si uno que [tú mismo consideraste importante](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2221/#comment9738_2221) no ha podido priorizarse en un año entero, ¿qué podemos esperar? Denota o bien una ausencia absoluta de interés de SE por los sitios internacionales, o bien que no se sabe poner suficiente presión al equipo de Joe Friend sobre las cosas que importan. Para el resto entiendo que debemos esperar y ver, ¡por favor mantennos informados!

Comment: !Gracias por editar mi respuesta! Es cierto que aun los reportes que he considerado como importantes han sido puestos en espera perpetua. Han habido muchos cambios internos este año lo cual nos ha perjudicado en cuanto a nuestra posición en la lista de espera pero seguiremos trayendo nuestras necesidades al equipo que puede ayudarnos. No vamos a dejar que esto se quede así.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer ya no hay CM específico para los sitios internacionales, que son considerados por igual respecto el resto de sitios.

También veo que [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) ya no trabaja para la empresa.

En cuanto a la salud de los sitios internacionales, me da la sensación que está bajando bastante el número de preguntas por día de los sitios internacionales (creo recordar que SOpt estaba en más de 100 preguntas diarias hace un tiempo). Para poder comparar, dejo aquí los datos a día 26 de junio de 2022 a partir de lo que aparece en la [lista de sitios](https://stackexchange.com/sites):

| sitio | questions | answers | answered | users | visits/day | questions/day | site age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO | 23m | 34m | 70% | 18m | 7.8m | 5.5k | 13y11m |
| SOpt | 153k | 189k | 77% | 250k | 48k | 53 | 8y6m |
| SOes | 177k | 192k | 60% | 267k | 56k | 103 | 6y6m |
| SOru | 420k | 454k | 68% | 317k | 62k | 178 | 7y3m |
| SOja | 28k | 33k | 77% | 37k | 7.3k | 9.5 | 7y6m |

Veo en [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3552/83) datos de 28 de junio de 2018:

| sitio | questions | answers | answered | users | visits/day | questions/day | site age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SO | 16m |  |  |  |  | 7k | 10y |
| SOes | 60k |  |  |  |  | 120 | 2y |

Answer (score -2):

Algunas preguntas tienen respuestas evidentes:

> ¿Qué ocurre con los bugs que se han acumulado con el tiempo y a los que no se ha encontrado recursos? Hace unos meses en el chat recopilamos los más urgentes y dio la sensación de que iban a resolverse, pero no ha sido el caso. Por si acaso, con Mariano nos pareció que podían ser:

Los recursos dedicados a los sitios internacionales han disminuido. Por tanto el la cantidad de errores que se van a resolver se reducirá.

> ¿Hay recursos para los SO internacionales? En los últimos años se ha pasado de un CM para cada uno de ellos a uno solo para los cuatro. Teniendo en cuenta que esto implica a una única persona gestionando cuatro idiomas tan diferentes como el ruso, el japonés, el portugués y el castellano, parece que la tarea puede resultar complicada.

El recurso más importante de una empresa en general son las personas que la componen. La reducción del número de personas dedicadas a los sitios internacionales es una indicación clara de un cambio de estrategia en SO en que estos sitios tienen una importancia reducida.

La retórica de relaciónes públicas será que sí, que somos importantes. Pero lo que importa son los hechos.

> ¿Cómo se está gestionando la carga de trabajo de los moderadores? SOes es la 6.ª comunidad en número de preguntas diarias (estadística completa). La 7.ª es SOpt, que tiene el doble de moderadores. Aparte de Unix&Linux, el resto de sitios de entre los diez primeros tienen como mínimo 5 moderadores. ¿Está en la agenda del CM gestionar este tema? Las estadísticas de trabajo de los moderadores son obviamente privadas, pero me encuentro con que en general los reportes tardan bastante en resolverse (y las consultas a veces no se contestan).

Habrá elecciones para añadir moderadores. Por supuesto los representantes de SO lo negarán hasta que se anuncien. Se niega porque lo contrario significaría reconocer que los actuales no son suficientes, es decir, reconocer la existencia de un problema, que es lo último que se hace en todo manual de relaciones públicas. Lo mismo pasó cuando Mendoza era el único moderador activo tras la desaparición de Coll. Al principio Garza dijo que no pero al final las cosas se caen por su propio peso y eligió a otros dos moderadores. Lo mismo sucederá otra vez.

> ¿Quién es el CM de SOes?

Nicolas en el papel. Nadie en la práctica. Decir que gestionar cuatro idiomas tan diferentes es complicado es un eufemismo. No se puede ser gestor de una comunidad hispanoparlate sin saber castellano. Estoy suponiendo que Nicolas no sabe castellano. Pero si me equivoco existe la posibilidad de que la situación mejore. Un cuarto de Nicolas podría ser mejor que lo visto hasta ahora.

Comment: Bien analizado. Ojalá la realidad no te dé la razón, pero la sensación sí es de que cada vez los sitios internacionales importan menos y así se ve en los movimientos estratégicos de la empresa.